# Probability of inequality of Random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent random variables with known distributions.

How can I calculate the distribution of $P(X_1<X_2<X_3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\Pr[X_1 < X_2 < X_3] \\
=& \sum_{x_2}\Pr[X_1 < x_2\ \land\ x_2 < X_3\mid X_2 = x_2] \cdot \Pr[X_2 = x_2] \\
=& \sum_{x_2} \Pr[X_1 < x_2] \cdot \Pr[X_3 > x_2] \cdot \Pr[X_2 = x_2]
\end{align}
assuming $X_2$ is discrete.

Comment: Basically, then, for every value of X2, sum the product that the probability that X2 is larger that L and smaller that H.
Makes sense intuitionally.